# Upgrade project from VS2017 to VS2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, upgrade, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0

I have been working on a project with VS2017. Target .NET Framework is 4.6.1 and I am using C# 7. However, I just installed VS2019. How can I upgrade my project to be able to use C# 8 features without any complications? As a matter of fact, everything works just fine with VS 2019. I just want to be able to access C# 8 features.

Comment: The IDE will stop you from doing this.  C# v8 requires runtime support that is only available in the .NETCore runtime, some of the improvements required substantial CLR modifications.  Porting your project to .NETCore is something you need to consider first.

Comment: Oh... I see. I think you should have posted this as an answer. It's a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

See the following link - [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019)

Visual Studio 2019 is mostly backwards compatible, and as long as your project type is listed in the docs above you should have no problems opening it in 2019.

Comment: I actually don't have a problem opening the project in VS2019. As a matter of fact, everything works fine just as before. I just want to be able to use C# 8 features.

Comment: C# language version is automatically selected by the compiler based on your framework version - [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

You can edit the csproj file however to force C# 8 - [Use C# 8 In Any .NET Project Today](https://montemagno.com/use-csharp-8-everywehre/)

Comment: So does this mean I have to manually upgrade the .NET framework for each project one by one?

Comment: Nope, you can use it with 4.6.1, you just have to edit the .csproj file in a text editor and insert `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>`

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work either. I read through the C# Language Versioning Documentation, including all the comments that followed. It seems that Microsoft locked manual .NET framework selection. I also confirmed this when I tried to select the .NET framework from the Project Properties advanced dialog box.

Comment: I tried starting a fresh project with VS 2019 and it also targets .NET 4.7.2, and C# 7.3 Have you actually created a project with VS2019 using C#8.0? If yes, how did you do it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check microsoft documentation:

C# 8.0 is supported only on .NET Core 3.x and newer versions. Many of the newest features require library and runtime features introduced in .NET Core 3.x:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Answer (score 0):

My best advice would be to backup your application code files and open the projects using VS2019 and see what happens, in most cases, in my experience they should be ok.

Most projects are compatible, unless they reference some obscure 3rd party libraries, that require specific versions of visual studio.